# Internal screen resolution changing with external monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution

Windows is telling me that my laptop screen (screen 1 in the below images) remains the same resolution when a smaller monitor (screen 3) is utilized; however, the image presented is larger and applications show less area. The smaller monitor is connected to the laptop's USB 3.0 port via a DisplayLink USB 3.0/VGA adapter. Screen 2 is connected VGA to VGA.

Can you explain why Windows is doing this and if I can stop it from doing so?

What additional information do you need?

Small monitor connected:
[image]

Without small monitor:
[image]